# JQUERY getting id of SORTABLE item that is dropped in DROPPABLE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-droppable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have sortable table elements.  I want to be able to take an item from the list into a trash (droppable) div.

I can get the id's of connected sortable's or drag/drop list.  But combining a sortable with a droppable has got me stumped.

```
$("#trash").droppable({
accept: "tr.sortable-row",
hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
drop: function(ev, ui) {

    var draggableId = $("tr.sortable-row").attr("id");
    var droppableId = $(this).attr("id");


    alert("Draggable ID: "+ draggableId+" Droppable ID: "+droppableId);
    ui.draggable.remove();
    $("#trash").html("<div><span><img style='height:100px; width:100px;'  src='/sis/images/trash.png' ></div>");
    var clickSound = new Audio('/sis/includes/trash.mp3');
    clickSound.play();

}});
```

draggableId is UNDEFINED

droppableId is the id of the trash droppable div.

How do I get the ID of the .sortable-row tr???

Comment: please make a jsfiddle with this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See those arguments to the drop function? `(ev, ui)`?  The second one is a set of handlers to the UI for the draggable item, *including the drag item itself*.  That's under `ui.helper`

If you used `original` or `clone` as an argument to the drag feature, then the original ID should still be there.  (I actually like to use the `about` attribute myself to store IDs that may not be unique-- parts of a display may be distributed across a page, and using the `typeof / about / property` HTML5 attributes lets me understand what objects I have on a page).  If you provided a function for a custom representation, it's your responsibility to provide the ID (in either the aformentioned `about` attribute, or in an HTML `data` attribute) to be read on drop.

Comment: I did a console.log(ui).  Then went through the DOM to find the values here: ui.helper.context.cells[0].attributes[2].value  -- there are 3 attributes (data-xxx values that are in the sortable tr that is dropped in the trash